# c++ function setting class varaibles, not keeping the new set value.

Tags: c++, function, class

I am making a game, and I am having a problem with making sure that the class value that is being set, stays set and does not return to what the constructor standard value is. I tried looking for something related to my problem, but I did not find one, so I apologize if this is a repeat.

```
void playerCombat(Hero hero, Enemy enemy, Item heroWeapon, Item enemyWeapon, Item heroArmor, Item enemyArmor)
{
int hp = 0;

int damage = 0;

if (heroWeapon.getType() == "Slice" && enemyArmor.getType() == "Light")
{
    damage = -enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense() + (rand() % 20 + 1) + (hero.getAttack() * 2);

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (enemy.getHP() - damage);
        enemy.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << hero.getName() << " missed." << endl;
    }
}
else if (heroWeapon.getType() == "Stab" && enemyArmor.getType() == "Medium")
{
    damage = -enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense() + (rand() % 20 + 1) + (hero.getAttack() * 2);

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (enemy.getHP() - damage);
        enemy.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << hero.getName() << " missed." << endl;
    }
}
else if (heroWeapon.getType() == "Blunt" && enemyArmor.getType() == "Heavy")
{
    damage = -enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense() + (rand() % 20 + 1) + (hero.getAttack() * 2);

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (enemy.getHP() - damage);
        enemy.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << hero.getName() << " missed." << endl;
    }
}
else if (heroWeapon.getType() == "Sword" && enemyArmor.getType() == "Medium")
{
    damage = -enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense() + (rand() % 20 + 1) + (hero.getAttack() * .5);

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (enemy.getHP() - damage);
        enemy.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << hero.getName() << "'s weapon was ineffective." << endl;
    }
}
else if (heroWeapon.getType() == "Stab" && enemyArmor.getType() == "Heavy")
{
    damage = -enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense() + (rand() % 20 + 1) + (hero.getAttack() * .5);

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (enemy.getHP() - damage);
        enemy.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << hero.getName() << "'s weapon was ineffective." << endl;
    }
}
else if (heroWeapon.getType() == "Blunt" && enemyArmor.getType() == "Light")
{
    damage = -enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense() + (rand() % 20 + 1) + (hero.getAttack() * .5);

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (enemy.getHP() - damage);
        enemy.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << hero.getName() << " missed." << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    damage = -enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense() + (rand() % 20 + 1) + (hero.getAttack());

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (enemy.getHP() - damage);
        enemy.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << hero.getName() << "'s weapon was ineffective." << endl;
    }
}
cout << hero.getName() << " deals " << damage << " points of damage to " << enemy.getName() << "." << endl;
cout << enemy.getName() << " has " << enemy.getHP() << " out of " << enemy.getMaxHp() << "." << endl;
cout << hero.getName() << " has " << hero.getHP() << " out of " << hero.getMaxHp() << "." << endl;
system("pause");


}

void enemyCombat(Hero hero, Enemy enemy, Item heroWeapon, Item enemyWeapon, Item heroArmor, Item enemyArmor)
{
int hp = 0;
int damage = 0;


if (enemyWeapon.getType() == "Slice" && heroArmor.getType() == "Light")
{
    damage = (rand() % 20 + 1) + (enemy.getAttack() * 2) - enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense();

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (hero.getHP() - damage);
        hero.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << enemy.getName() << " missed" << endl;
    }
}
else if (enemyWeapon.getType() == "Stab" && heroArmor.getType() == "Medium")
{
    damage = (rand() % 20 + 1) + (enemy.getAttack() * 2) - enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense();

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (hero.getHP() - damage);
        hero.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << enemy.getName() << " missed" << endl;
    }
}
else if (enemyWeapon.getType() == "Blunt" && heroArmor.getType() == "Heavy")
{
    damage = (rand() % 20 + 1) + (enemy.getAttack() * 2) - enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense();

    if (damage > 0)
    {

        hp = (hero.getHP() - damage);
        hero.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << enemy.getName() << " missed" << endl;
    }
}
else if (enemyWeapon.getType() == "Sword" && heroArmor.getType() == "Medium")
{
    damage = (rand() % 20 + 1) + (enemy.getAttack() * .5) - enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense();

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (hero.getHP() - damage);
        hero.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << enemy.getName() << "'s attack was ineffective." << endl;
    }
}
else if (enemyWeapon.getType() == "Stab" && heroArmor.getType() == "Heavy")
{
    damage = (rand() % 20 + 1) + (enemy.getAttack() * .5) - enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense();

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (hero.getHP() - damage);
        hero.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << enemy.getName() << "'s attack was ineffective." << endl;
    }
}
else if (enemyWeapon.getType() == "Blunt" && heroArmor.getType() == "Light")
{
    damage = (rand() % 20 + 1) + (enemy.getAttack() * .5) - enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense();

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (hero.getHP() - damage);
        hero.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << enemy.getName() << "'s attack was ineffective." << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    damage = (rand() % 20 + 1) + (enemy.getAttack()) - enemyArmor.getDefense() - enemy.getDefense();

    if (damage > 0)
    {
        hp = (hero.getHP() - damage);
        hero.setHp(hp);
    }
    else
    {
        damage = 0;
        cout << enemy.getName() << "' missed." << endl;
    }
}
cout << enemy.getName() << " deals " << damage << " points of damage to " << hero.getName() << "." << endl;
cout << enemy.getName() << " has " << enemy.getHP() << " out of " << enemy.getMaxHp() << "." << endl;
cout << hero.getName() << " has " << hero.getHP() << " out of " << hero.getMaxHp() << "." << endl;
system("pause");


}

void combat(Hero hero, Enemy enemy, Item heroWeapon, Item enemyWeapon, Item heroArmor, Item enemyArmor)
 {



if (hero.getSpeed() > enemy.getSpeed())
{
    playerCombat(hero, enemy, heroWeapon, enemyWeapon, heroArmor, enemyArmor);

    enemyCombat(hero, enemy, heroWeapon, enemyWeapon, heroArmor, enemyArmor);

}
else if (hero.getSpeed() < enemy.getSpeed())
{
    playerCombat(hero, enemy, heroWeapon, enemyWeapon, heroArmor, enemyArmor);

    enemyCombat(hero, enemy, heroWeapon, enemyWeapon, heroArmor, enemyArmor);

}
else
{
    if ((rand() % 2 + 1) == 1)
    {
        playerCombat(hero, enemy, heroWeapon, enemyWeapon, heroArmor, enemyArmor);

        enemyCombat(hero, enemy, heroWeapon, enemyWeapon, heroArmor, enemyArmor);
    }
    else
    {
        playerCombat(hero, enemy, heroWeapon, enemyWeapon, heroArmor, enemyArmor);

        enemyCombat(hero, enemy, heroWeapon, enemyWeapon, heroArmor, enemyArmor);
    }
    cout << hero.getHP() << endl << enemy.getHP() << endl;
}
if (enemy.getHP() < 0)
{
    cout << "You lose!";
}
else if (hero.getHP() < 0)
{
    cout << "You win!";
}
else
{
    combat(hero, enemy, heroWeapon, enemyWeapon, heroArmor, enemyArmor);
}
}
```

For some reason after the functions for the specific character combat ends, it does not retain the new HP value, and simply resets it back their full hp (in this case 100)

Comment: Could you reduce this to a [MCVE], and be more specific what's actually going wrong please.

Answer (score 1):

You passed objects by value into the function but you wanted to make lasting changes to those objects.  C++ doesn't work that way for pass by value.

So you should have passed by reference:

```
void playerCombat(Hero& hero, Enemy& enemy, Item& heroWeapon, Item& enemyWeapon, Item& heroArmor, Item& enemyArmor)
```

Similarly for all of the other functions that are supposed to modify the objects passed to them.

I showed suggested edits to the "signature" line of playerCombat.  Fix the signature lines of every function:

If you pass an object that will be modified inside the function and you **DON'T** want those modifications to affect the original (you want the modifications to only last during the execution of the function) pass by value, such as `Hero hero`

If you pass an object that will be modified inside the function and you want those modifications to affect the original pass by reference, such as `Hero& hero`

If you pass an object that will **NOT** be modified inside the function, it is usually best to pass by const reference, such as `Hero const& hero`

Comment: const reference for unmodified objects.

Comment: I didn't read the posted code carefully enough to see whether any of the passed objects were supposed to be never modified by the function.  Any that were never modified would work correctly when passed by value, but would be better passed by `const&`

Answer (score 0):

You pass variables to function by value, actually in function you work with copies of them. You need pass variables by reference, like

```
void playerCombat(Hero &hero, Enemy &enemy, Item &heroWeapon, Item &enemyWeapon, Item &heroArmor, Item &enemyArmor)
```

Comment: So that means I'll have to go into my classes and overload the & operator?

Comment: Unless you have a very bizarre meaning for your use of the word "overload", the three (basically identical) answers you got **DO NOT** mean that.  Just look at where the `&`s were added in the signature of those functions and add `&`s in function signatures that way for every object for which you want modifications made inside the function to affect the original object.